# No output in twig with custom Form Class

Tags: forms, symfony, twig

I made an very small testformular to teach myself with custom Form Classes in Synfomy. I dont have a output and i dont find the mistake. I hope someone can help me.

My From Class:

```
<?php
  namespace AppBundle\Form;

  use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
  use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;
  use Symfony\Component\OptionsResolver\OptionsResolver;
  use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\TextType;

  class PfsFormType extends AbstractType
  {
     public function buildTheForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
  {
      $builder
        ->add('name')
    ;
}
   public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
   {
    $resolver->setDefaults(array(
        'data_class' => 'AppBundle\Entity\PfsForm'
    ));
   }
}
```

my entity:

```
<?php
namespace AppBundle\Entity;

class PfsForm
{
private $name;
private $frage;

/**
 * @return mixed
 */
public function getFrage()
{
    return $this->frage;
}

/**
 * @param mixed $frage
 */
public function setFrage($frage)
{
    $this->frage = $frage;
}

/**
 * @return mixed
 */
public function getName()
{
    return $this->name;
}

/**
 * @param mixed $name
 */
public function setName($name)
{
    $this->name = $name;
}

}
```

The Controller which should call the form:

```
<?php

namespace AppBundle\Controller;

use AppBundle\Entity\PfsForm;
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;
use AppBundle\Form\PfsFormType;

class IndexController extends Controller
{
    public function startAction()
    {
    $pfsForm =  new PfsForm();
    $form = $this->createForm(PfsFormType::class,$pfsForm );
       return $this->render(
       'index.html.twig',array(
           'form' => $form->createView(),
       )
       );
    }
}
```

And the twig template:

```
enter code here

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Title</title>
</head>
<body>
{{ dump() }}
{{ form_start(form) }}
     {{ form_widget(form) }}
{{ form_end(form) }}
 </body>
</html>
```

Thats the Twig dump output:

```
    array:2 [▼
    "form" => FormView {#408 ▼
+vars: array:24 [▼
  "value" => PfsForm {#361 ▶}
  "attr" => []
  "form" => FormView {#408}
  "id" => "pfs_form"
  "name" => "pfs_form"
  "full_name" => "pfs_form"
  "disabled" => false
  "label" => null
  "label_format" => null
  "multipart" => false
  "block_prefixes" => array:3 [▶]
  "unique_block_prefix" => "_pfs_form"
  "translation_domain" => null
  "cache_key" => "_pfs_form_pfs_form"
  "errors" => FormErrorIterator {#419 ▶}
  "valid" => true
  "data" => PfsForm {#361 ▶}
  "required" => true
  "size" => null
  "label_attr" => []
  "compound" => true
  "method" => "POST"
  "action" => ""
  "submitted" => false
]
+parent: null
+children: array:1 [▼
  "_token" => FormView {#424 ▶}
]
-rendered: false
  }
  "app" => AppVariable {#435 ▼
    -tokenStorage: TokenStorage {#239 ▶}
    -requestStack: RequestStack {#200 ▶}
    -environment: "dev"
    -debug: true
  }
 ]
```

Thx for your help
Micha

Answer (score 2):

Method that you are trying to use with forms `buildTheForm` is not the right name!

Try using `buildForm` which is the correct one:

```
class PfsFormType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
            ->add('name')
        ;
    }
}
```

http://symfony.com/doc/current/forms.html

Comment: Thank u so much for your help. I dont understand where do u know from,that the name of the Method should be "buildForm" and not "whatEverName" ?

Comment: @freemindghost, oh its actually fairly easy to find out. See that `PfsFormType extends AbstractType`. Well this means your class `PfsFormType` overrides methods from `AbstractType`. If you open it, you can see that it has `function buildForm()` which has no body..meaning that you have to implement its body in your class yourself. Good luck ;)

Comment: i normally work with interfaces so i get a message to use the methods i define.thx you so much for your help